# How to retrieve data from API and write in a Json file with nodejs

Tags: node.js, file

I'm trying to get data from API and write it in Json File. How can I do that please?
the function to retrive the data is:

```
 function get_flights_by_airport(airport_name, callback) {
    let request = require('request');
    let url = 'http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=xxxx'
    request(url, function (err, response, body) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('error:', error);
        callback(err);
      } else {
        let vol = JSON.parse(body)
        num = vol.pagination.count
        result = []
        for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
          dep = vol.data[i].departure.airport
          one_flight = {number: vol.data[i].flight.number, date: vol.data[i].flight_date, departure: vol.data[i].departure.timezone, arrival: vol.data[i].arrival.timezone, from: vol.data[i].departure.airport, to: vol.data[i].arrival.airport}
          result.push(one_flight)
         
          }
        callback(null, result)
      }
   });}
```

Comment: You could check the filesystem module [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). It has APIs like `writeFile` and `writeFileSync` which could be used to write to a file. And use `JSON.stringify` to convert your JSON object to a string before writing it.

Comment: Hi Mariem. Please check the answer and mark the question as answered if it so. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `fs` module. The fs module enables interacting with the file system in a way modeled on standard POSIX functions.
All file system operations have synchronous, callback, and promise-based forms.

Here is an example of the synchronous way to write file

```
const fs = require('fs');


fs.writeFileSync(`${FILE_PATH}.json`, JSON.stringify(YOUR_JSON));
```

Replace `FILE_PATH` to the path where you want to save the file and `YOUR_JSON` to your JSON.